# Find where datetime in Python df1 is between 2 datetime values in df2

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have 2 dataframes in Python like this:

df1:

| Person_ID | Event_DateTime |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 05/12/2023 15:34 |
| 12346 | 5/1/2023 09:45 |

df2:

| Person_ID | Start_Time | End_Time | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 05/11/2023 18:34 | 05/12/2023 15:12 | Building 1 |
| 12345 | 05/12/2023 15:13 | 05/12/2023 21:08 | Building 2 |
| 12345 | 05/12/2023 21:09 | 05/12/2023 21:59 | Building 3 |
| 12346 | 5/1/2023 07:01 | 5/1/2023 07:34 | Building Green |
| 12346 | 5/1/2023 07:34 | 5/1/2023 08:55 | Building Yellow |
| 12346 | 5/1/2023 08:56 | 5/1/2023 10:22 | Building Orange |

I want to take each Person_ID from df1, find the corresponding row that matches the person_ID AND where the Event_DateTime is between the Start_Time and End_Time from df2, and return the Location. The resulting df should look like this:

df_3:

| Person_ID | Event_DateTime | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 05/12/2023 15:34 | Building 2 |
| 12346 | 5/1/2023 09:45 | Building Orange |

I am struggling to get this to work. Any ideas?

Many thanks!

I tried the vlookup approach, but can't get it to search between 2 values. An exact match would be easy. I have a few thousand rows to process, so I need something moderately efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be sure sure that the `datetime` columns in both `dataframes` are of type `datetime`, then we merge the two `dataframes` on 'Person_ID' and filter the rows where '`Event_DateTime`' is between '`Start_Time`' and '`End_Time`'.

```
import pandas as pd

df1['Event_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Event_DateTime'])
df2['Start_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start_Time'])
df2['End_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['End_Time'])

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Person_ID', how='left')

df = df[df.apply(lambda row: row['Start_Time'] <= row['Event_DateTime'] <= row['End_Time'], axis=1)]

df = df[['Person_ID', 'Event_DateTime', 'Location']]
```

Comment: This did the trick! You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two tables on `Person_ID` and then filter it down to the correct time slot using `query`.

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on="Person_ID").query(
    "Event_DateTime >= Start_Time and Event_DateTime <= End_Time"
)[['Person_ID', 'Event_DateTime', 'Location']]
```